# Selecting nested element with vars

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a function and for simplicity I want to create a few vars to reuse, however, I'm a bit confused how to select an element when parent is a var.

Can I do something like:

```
var parent_em = $('#my_container'),
    child_em  = $('.my_child_em', parent_em);
```

instead of

```
$('#my_container').find('.my_child_em')...
```

or

```
$('#my_container .my_child_em')...
```

Comment: Yes.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You can also do `var child_em = parent_em.find(".my_child_em");`

Comment: Thanks. I also wanted to create a var for a child as it's going to be used in the function later. But, in general, is this a correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the first approach:

```
child_em  = $('.my_child_em', parent_em);
```

you need to consider how jQuery constructor works:

> [jQuery( selector [, context ] )](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1): By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function. For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be restricted.

Hence, it's a perfect way to reduce the context in wich to search for.